# Добавляем правильное отображение input type="range" в старых браузерах

Tags: html5, javascript

Добавил к себе в проект поле

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="200" step="1" value="50"/>
```

, но понятное дело, что в старых браузерах, которые не поддерживают HTML5, поле просто отображается как текстовое. Вопрос - возможно есть какое-то готовое решение на JavaScript, чтобы поле с type="range" отображалось как следует?

Может кому-нибудь пригодится -

```
<input type="color" class="color" value="FF0000" />
```

можно отображать в старых браузерах с помощью

[JSColor](http://www.jscolor.com)

, нужно лишь вставить в тег head -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

самое что есть, так это вот такое решение:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно. У меня сейчас стоит FireFox 3.6.10, так что это решение только для IE, а мне нужно кроссбраузерное, однако все равно спасибо за помощь!